# How we can integrate Qr code monkey api to an express.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Integrate this for https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo

For this code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require("https");

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("req",req.body);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the question you're asking here.

My guess is that you're trying to interact with the `qrcode-monkey` API using express.js?

If that's true, following the [qrcode-monkey API documentation](https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo) you'll have to invoke (in this case) express to issue either a `GET` or `POST` request to the correct end point `/qr/transparent` with the required data both in the request body and head. this is documented in the link you provided

since you're doing this via express it's I *assume* you're going to be passing the URL that the qr code points to via your endpoint then to the 3rd party API. This might looking something like this.

```js
router.get('/:url', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.params.url) next(new Error('400 missing url param'))
    try {
        res.body.qr = await fetch('https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/transparent',
            {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: { ... },
              body: { ... }
            }
         ).json()
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
    res.json(req.body.qr)
})
```

*note: this is pesudo code and shouldn't just be copy/pasted.*

---

I suggest refering to the express.js [documentation](https://expressjs.com/)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432139/how-do-i-write-a-node-js-request-to-3rd-party-api) seems to go into more detail about 3rd party API interation with express.